# How to remove Object from Array based on ID in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React app that populates table based on input. It mimics employee management app but on the most basic level.

I have three components.

In `App.js` I just render `Table` component.

`Table` component has state for handling employees.

```
  const [employeeData, setEmployeeData] = useState([]);

  const addRow = (data) => {
    const updatedTotalEmployees = [...employeeData];
    updatedTotalEmployees.push(data);
    setEmployeeData(updatedTotalEmployees);
  };
```

Then I `map` it in the `<tr>` and `<td>` parts of table.

Here I am rendering `Form` component and passing props to it

```
  <InputContainer addRow={addRow} />
```

I have third component that handles form that I pass props from `Table` component to it.

```
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  // const [deleteId, setDeleteId] = useState("");

  const handleAdding = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const employee = { id, firstName, lastName };
    addRow(employee);
  };
```

And on every input I have onChange based on state. For example:

```
 onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
```

In this component, as you can see by the state I have three input fields for adding it's value to the table.

I have fourth input field and the button that I want to use to delete Employee from the table based on ID. So I will type ID in the input field and if that ID is present in the table I want to remove that employee from the table on the click of the button.

I guess I have to have another state for fourth input field, but I am not sure how I would go about deleting from table based on ID. Do I use `.filter()` method or some other? Or do I target object index?

Do I have logic for deleting row in `Table` component then have logic for handling form for deletion in `InputContainer` component.

Here is the sandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-vaughan-6nbe8p?file=/src/InputContainer.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not clear. would be great if you could provide a codesandbox link.

From what I understood, first, since you are using the state to store employee data, you can add employee data in the following way.

```
  const addRow = (data) => {   
 setEmployeeData(previousEmployeeData => [...previousEmployeeData, data]);
  };
```

And you can remove a selected index from the state simply by using `filter` method as follow

```
setEmployeeData(previousEmployeeData => previousEmployeeData.filter((data)=> data.id != employeeId ))
```

*[*Ref. MDN: The filter() method creates a shallow copy of a portion of a given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)*

Here I'm referring  `employeeId` to the `id` which you want to delete

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear enough.

Here is the sandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-vaughan-6nbe8p?file=/src/InputContainer.js

Comment: I have changed the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-snowflake-pld4rz?file=/src/App.js  check it out. you cannot filter the state from a different component without passing it via props. i bought the delete function to the same component